# Query parameterized cannot insert value with c# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a parameterized query and it was working fine, but when I delete de DB and create it again, with the same values and everything, it throws an exception that says it cannot insert value NULL with the value sexo, but all the values are assigned, here it's the code:

```
    try{
      var cmdPersona_Log = new SqlCommand();
      cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.Clear();
      cmdPersona_Log.Connection = mySqlConnection;
      cmdPersona_Log.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmdPersona_Log.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Tomin].[TominRH].[Persona_Log] "
       + "([Id_Action],[Id_User],[Id_Date],[Id_Entidad],[Nombre],[Paterno],[Materno],[Sexo],[Id_Nacionalidad])"
       + " Values (1, 'Admin', @fecha, @id_entidad, @nombre, @paterno, @materno, @sexo, 52)";
      cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", DateTime.Now);
      cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_entidad", dbRow["CUENTA"].ToString().Trim());
      cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre ?? string.Empty);
      cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paterno", paterno ?? string.Empty);
      cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@materno", materno ?? string.Empty);
      cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", 1);
      cmdPersona_Log.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch(Exception e) 
   {
      MessageBox.Show(dbRow["CUENTA"] + " Persona_log  " + e.ToString());
   }
```

I've checked the DB and it doesn't seem to be the problem, any sugestion??

Comment: What type are nombre, paterno and materno?

Comment: string, but the problem is with sexo, I forgot to say that...

Comment: try using `true` instead of 1 with `AddWithValue`

Comment: Exactly the same problem, the data type is bit not boolean, I don't know if it's the same, but I think it's something with the parameterized values...

Comment: The second parameter to this method is of type Object inference is used what happens if you replace 1 with true?

Comment: There is no `Boolean` type in `SQL`.  A `bit` in SQL is translated to `bool` in .NET and vice-versa.

Comment: But you're getting the same exception using `true`?

Comment: And it only happens after you clean out the database?

Comment: Yes, the exactly same exception

Comment: It happens with all the queries that use that table

Comment: Are there any triggers or other constraints on the table?

Comment: Yes there are, but the constraints has nothing to do with the value that causes the exception

Comment: Can you use SQL profiler to see what query is being executed?

Comment: I don't know what SQL profiler is... Can you help me with that??

Comment: Are you using SQL server? It would be good to see the SQL that is sent to the dB but I believe it is sent as a prepared statement. So it is not easy to see from the qry object in c#. If you start the profiler tool running on the target dB you should be able to see what it is trying to execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be running into a case where `AddWithValue` isn't inferring your parameter type of `bit` properly.  Use `true`/`false` instead of `1`/`0`:

```
cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", true);
```

Comment: Yes, that I cannot insert NULL value

Comment: @poz2k4444 And if you get rid of the parameter and change the sql to use 1 instead of the sexo parameter, what happens?

Comment: The same exception, indeed I changed to parameterized query because I had what you say

Comment: I don't know why, but there is no problem anymore, I left the project a few days and suddenly everything works just fine :S, any way, thanks for the help...

Comment: +1 having spoken to the original author, this recommendation, as we both expected fixed the problem. see comments attached to my answer. I suspect (although it is unproven) that the code changes were not being built between runs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all fields of the table which are supposed to be not null are listed in the INSERT-clause

Comment: CHecked... The table has 10 parameters and 9 cannot be NULL and those are the parameters that I send...

Comment: @poz2k4444 Can you you give sql-expression which creates the table?

Comment: I don't know why, but there is no problem anymore, I left the project a few days and suddenly everything works just fine :S, any way, thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this form 
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value =`
where you can be explicit about the SqlDbType?

Comment: I don't know why, but there is no problem anymore, I left the project a few days and suddenly everything works just fine :S, any way, thanks for the help...

Comment: I have had this problem in the past where the project was not really running the re-built changes made to your code so effectively re-running the broken code even once you had fixed it. This can sometime lead to breaking the code even more with edits apparently not leading to any change in behaviour. Just out of interest is your  working code exactly the same as your original post? I believe a few of us thought `cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", 1);` would not work.

Comment: MY code is working with cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", true);
that was the last change I made and then I left the project for a few days... How could I know when the code is running with the changes I made??

Comment: Rebuild All. Also if you suspect your latest changes are not being used deliberately break it by throwing and exception in code that has to be executed. If no exception is thrown your code changes are not being used. Both @user:1081897 and myself suspected that you needed to change `cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", 1);` to `cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", true);` and have commented as such. It does appear from your response that it dis not work. I think it is worth editing and Up-voting D Stanley, to help future viewers of this question.

Comment: I did change `cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", 1);` to `cmdPersona_Log.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", true);` This is the last change I did, and when it throws an exception, It always throwed the exception mentioned, and suddenly it doens't, I don't know why but the code is working perfect by now, anyway I appreciate your help guys, thanks a lot!